# Ошибка при разном имени const и id JS

Tags: javascript, dom

Всем привет. Может кто-то знает, что это может быть? Задаю const, проверяю в консоли, выдает ошибку. Задаю значение const в консоли, работает. Но если задать одинаковое имя const  с id все начинает работать.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Ваш код

```
const adu = ...
```

завернут в функцию или блок `{ ... }`, `adu` - локальная константа, которая не видна в консоли.

```js
console.log(adu1);
console.log(adu2);
```

```html
<script>
const adu1 = 123;
{
  const adu2 = 456;
}
</script>
```

---

> если задать одинаковое имя const с id все начинает работать

Это давний аспект поведения JS в браузерах - в `window` добавляются свойства для элементов с заданными `id`.

```js
console.log(abc, window.def);
```

```html
<div id="abc"></div>
<div id="def"></div>
```